# Is it Possible install git in xampp localhost?

Tags: apache, git, localhost, xampp

Is it Possible  hooked git into XAMPP so it can be managed as part of that software suite.? i try to make my own remote repository

Comment: I think the real question should be, can git-daemon (http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) be somehow hooked into XAMPP so it can be managed as part of that software suite.

Comment: @voyagerfan5761 yes, that it the question. i will edit my previous question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a webserver for git. So if you're talking about accessing the files within your git repository over the web, just install your git repository and check it out to a directory beneath your apaches DocumentRoot.